# .NET Connector only returns first record

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a weird 'bug/error', at the the .NET Connector only returns to me one record while there are 5 or something. The MySQL Command Line also returns 1. Here is the code I'm really stuck with this, I try to make a Client-Server and let the Client login from a DB at the Server Computer:

[image: Proof]

[image: Weird bug]

Code:

```
string strConnect = "server=localhost;user=root;password=xxxx;database=MoopleDEV";
string query = "SELECT name FROM accounts;";

using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    connection.Open();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString("name"));
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

**Note:** It also returns only 'iVision' at the MySQL Command Line Client. Anyone knows what to do?
*Ps:* It doesn't crash or return any exception.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the same database? You talk about a 'login to a server computer' but your connection string specifies 'localhost' (your own computer)

Comment: Oh yea, the server and client are debugged at my own computer, and I have the MySQL DB on my computer running. (Its the idea the server program is going to run at an server computer)

Comment: why are you using `reader.GetString` I have seen too many issues with that why not use the `(string)reader["name"]` approach also when you run the query how many rows are you returning when running the Query Manually also make sure that you are really looking at the right DB `database=MoopleDEV` could be incorrect or pointed to a different IP Address or location on your Physical Machine

Comment: also reader.GetString() requires an integer as column index not a string name (at least in SqlDataReader)

Comment: @Steve You can enter an index or the column name.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Well you gave me an idea, I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 and it works now, really weird imo glad it works though :) Should I reply it as an answer?

Comment: If you are using [maketime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_maketime), there is a [known bug](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,137839) that causes the .NET connector to return only one row

Comment: `IVision` looks at some of the suggestions and I am glad that I was able to point you to some idea's as to what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IVision I hope that this will give you an idea

why are you using reader.GetString I have seen too many issues with that why not use the `(string)reader["name"]` approach also when you run the query how many rows are you returning when running the Query Manually also make sure that you are really looking at the right DB database=MoopleDEV could be incorrect or pointed to a different IP Address or location on your Physical Machine. I would also name my local Database Instance to an actual `Name` as well would cause less confusion

Comment: Like I already commented on your comment, localhost somehow doesn't work correct. If I enter 127.0.0.1 as IP It works fine:) Thank you for the idea you brought up to me :) (PS: reader[<name>] seems nicer too btw :P)

Answer (score 1):

You are re-opening your connection after creating your reader.  Move your connection open statement before you create your command object.

Try this instead:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
    using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString("name"));
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What you mean? I do not re-open it? Or do you mean MySQLCommand opens the connection automatically?

Comment: Once you say command.ExecuteReader(), the connection is automatically opened. Then, within the scope of the open reader, you call connection.Open(), which cuts-off and re-opens the connection, but the reader's datastream has been cut off. It seems odd that there is one record in the stream before you even call reader.Read(). Still, that is what you are getting.

Comment: I don't know if I'm that stupid but you only put connection.Close() at the end of the using statement which is not even needed because it gets automatically closed and disposed.
Sorry if I'm making a stupid mistake haha

Comment: True.  It is optional.  I just do it out of habit.